# My app always print information like following, what the reason and how to solve it?

Tags: android, eclipse

08-23 11:38:27.070: D/dalvikvm(6930): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 636K, 47% free 3323K/6211K, external 618K/904K, paused 66ms

Comment: need more details, where does it keep printing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its printed in log and it just states what
 **GC(Garbage Collector)_FOR_MALLOC** has done: this generally means that your application had to allocate more memory
because first GC_CONCURRENT is called to clear heap and if it requires more memory this is called.

**636k** of memory  is the amount of memory freed .

**47% free 3323K/6211K**  Heap size is 6211k and now 47 % of it is free , currently occupied heap is 3323K

**external 618K/904K**  externally allocate memory first number is the amount of memory allocated and second is a soft limit.

**paused 66ms** pause time for collection  , larger heap more time.

Source : http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_CruQY55HOk

Comment: So I guess some code in my app cost a lot of RAM, and now I cancel these code and my app operates normally, thanks

Answer (score 0):

This message doesn't come from you app but from the Dalvik garbage collector.